# Existe alguma forma de estilizar o botão de redimensionamento?

Tags: html, css

**Exemplo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            resize: both;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

No exemplo acima você consegue redimensionar a `div` para cima e para baixo ou para os lados, minha pergunta é se nesse botão que é usado para redimensionar a `div` tem como ser estilizado.

Comment: Isso pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580795/possible-to-style-the-css3-resize-function

Comment: @MarceloBoni, Valeu! ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [jQuery UI Draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) para isso. Em vez de usar a propriedade `resize: both;`, você coloca um elemento estilizado como quiser no canto inferior direito da div aplicando o draggable nele. À medida que você move o elemento com o mouse, a div onde ele está é redimensionada.

No exemplo abaixo coloquei um `span` quadrado vermelho que simula a área de redimensionamento da div:

```js
$(function(){
   $("#draggable").draggable({
      drag: function(event, ui){
         
         var el = $(event.target);
         var el_width = el.width();
         var el_height = el.height();
         var div = el.parent();
         var div_width = div.width();
         var div_height = div.height();
         var div_padd_top = parseInt(div.css("padding-top"));
         var div_padd_right = parseInt(div.css("padding-right"));
         var div_padd_bottom = parseInt(div.css("padding-bottom"));
         var div_padd_left = parseInt(div.css("padding-left"));
         var hor = el_width - (div_width - ui.position.left + div_padd_left + div_padd_right);
         var ver = el_height - (div_height - ui.position.top + div_padd_top + div_padd_bottom);
   
         // evita redimensionamento se a div for menor que o span
         if(ui.position.left < el_width || ui.position.top < el_height){
            return false;
         }

         div.css({
            width  : div_width+hor+"px",
            height : div_height+ver+"px"
         });
         
      }
   });
});
```

```css
div{
   width: 300px;
   height: 150px;
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   /* resize: both; REMOVIDO */
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   padding: 20px;
}

#draggable{
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: red;
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   cursor: all-scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   <span id="draggable"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito! muito obrigado. 